# Unexpected behaviour of a c program?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, undefined-behavior

This code is not giving the output as expected and clearly i cant understand the program behaviour.Plz help me in understanding this.Any Help will be appreciated.
You can see the output of the program https://code.hackerearth.com/31d954z?key=fce7bc8e07fc10a3d7a693e45a5af94a here.

> 1.In the last comment, I can't find why the elements of array are not updated.
>
> 2.In the body of func on printing 'a' it gives some unexpected output.
>
> For e.g., if i pass j = 2 and a[0] = 1
>
> ```
>        After j = j+1 , which results in j = 3;
>
>        a=a+j should result in a = 4
>
>        but instead it result in a = 13.
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int j,int *a)
{
 j=j+1;
 printf("%d\t%d\n",a,j);     //prints j updated value and a
 a=a+j;
 printf("a = %d\n ",a);      //prints value of a
}


void main()
{
 int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5},i,j=2;
 for (i =0;i<5;i++ )
 func(j, a[i]);
 for (i =0;i<5;i++ )   
 printf("%d\t",a[i]);    //Prints the array as 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

On running this code,Output is :

> `1   3   // Here a = 1 and j = 3
>   a = 13      //but after addition a = 13
>    2  3
>   a = 14
>    3  3
>   a = 15
>    4  3
>   a = 16
>    5  3
>   a = 17
>    1 2 3 4 5   //array elements not updated`

Comment: A good compiler should give you warnings about an invalid conversion of an `int` to an `int*`. And you print and update the *pointer* in the function, not what `a` is pointing to (which is good since you would probably have crashes if you did).

Comment: Though you *still* have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you print a pointer using the `"%d"` format which is for printing `int` values. To print a pointer you need to use the `"%p"` format and a `void*` argument (cast *is* needed).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion.Can you plzz help me in correcting this @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If your program (any program) compiles with warnings, you should stop trying to run it and start thinking about how to fix the warnings. Don't even ask why the result is wrong. Nobody cares. Fix the warnings first. If you don't know how, ask a question specifically about the warnings. If this specific program compiles without warnings, your compiler is broken and you need to find a better compiler.

Comment: @Shubh Tripathi There is a tiny difference (just the `*` symbol) between the `int` and `int *`. I advice to buy a good C book as arrays and pointers look as some kind of mystery for you.

Comment: (Continued) If you are using gcc or clang, add -Wall -Werror to the compilation flags. This way you won't miss important stuff. If you are using a Microsoft IDE, there are warning options buried in the project properties dialogue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to understand the code behavior.

Your code produces **Undefined Behavior**, thus you should stop what you are doing and *debug* it.

---

When you want to *index* arrays you do it like this:

```
a[i]
```

where `i` is the index and `a` your array. So if you want to access the first element, you need to do `a[0]`, when you want to index the 3rd element, you do `a[2]` and so on.

---

However, what you may want to do is something like passing the i-th element, add it and print it, only.

So, you should enable your compiler warnings:

```
prog.c: In function 'func':
prog.c:6:11: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d\t%d\n",a,j);     //prints j updated value and a
          ~^
          %ls
prog.c:8:15: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
  printf("a = %d\n ",a);      //prints value of a
              ~^
              %ls
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:12:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^~~~
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:16:10: warning: passing argument 2 of 'func' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  func(j, a[i]);
          ^
prog.c:3:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
 void func(int j,int *a)
      ^~~~
```

and then modify your code accordingly, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int j,int a)
{
 j=j+1;
 printf("%d\t%d\n",a,j);   
 a=a+j;
 printf("a = %d\n ",a);
}


int main(void)
{
 int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5},i,j=2;
 for (i =0;i<5;i++ )
 func(j, a[i]);
 for (i =0;i<5;i++ )   
 printf("%d\t",a[i]);
}
```

which outputs:

```
1   3
a = 4
 2  3
a = 5
 3  3
a = 6
 4  3
a = 7
 5  3
a = 8
 1  2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo error, it was a[i] only.But even its a[i] the output is still not as expected.

Comment: May be you are correct, i ve generated these outputs in an online compiler(Code Table by Hackerearth) but why the values in original array remains unaffected.

Comment: @ShubhTripathi I updated my answer, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanx @gsamaras But what to do when I want to change the value of elements in the array by passing every single element.Is it possible??And also why it was printing 13 14 15 16 17??

Comment: @ShubhTripathi I think I have misunderstood the question. What exactly is that you want to do?

Comment: I want to understand the code behavior.Please go through the link provided in the question and try to run it.It's not printing as it should be.

Comment: This is turning into a chameleon question:(

Comment: @MartinJames thanks for the upvote..yes it does... Shubh I updated my answer, now I think it's OK! I executed your online code and guess what! I got different results from you; that's a classic when you are dealing with Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're giving value to the function which expects a pointer.

```
void func(int j,int *a) // a is a pointer
```

And this is what you pass:

```
func(j, a[i]); // a[i] is a value
```

You should pass an address of value you want to change. In that way, if value changed on func, the main will also have the changed value. If you pass by value, func will change that value on stack (because function arguments go to stack) and main will have old unaltered value. To pass reference to value you want to change use this:

```
func(j, a + i); //a is address to start of array
```

Of course, in the function, you should increment value then, not the address:

```
*a += j; // Instead of a = a + j where 'a' is pointer according your function
```